# Finding sql date with account year and Quarter

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-date-functions, sqldatetime

I am  new in sql i am facing one problem
I need to create stored procedure which return start and end date of any quarter by passing Quarters as string string and year

ex : when i pass `exec spname '2014-15','jul-sep'`, it should  start date of july and end date of September

Comment: With you example of `exec spname '2014-15','jul-sep'` what resulset do you expect?

Comment: it should return output as  start date of july and end date of September

Comment: Please provide specific output in your question - exact values, not a description.

Comment: when execute stored procedure                                                                 t It should return 01-07-2014 as startdateofquter and  30-09-2014 as end date of quter  (sql version 2014)

Comment: The input will always be correct or the SP should be able to manage something link `exec spname '2014-15','aug-sep'` or `exec spname '2014-15','jul-aug'` returning the value `01-07-2014` and `30-09-2014`?

Comment: What do you mean by "it not working"?   If you are getting an error message, please include it in your question.

Comment: @TabAlleman i posted logic which i develop

Comment: @Serpiton year and Quter will be dynamic so if i provide 2014-15 and oct-dec it shoud return firstdate of oct and last date of dec

Comment: My question was if the input can be different from the correct start and end of the quarter oct-dec if the fourth quarter, calling the SP with a wrong month do you expect an error or the SP should manage it in some way?

Comment: @Serpiton offcourse it shoud print error with wrong month

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is unclear why you do not provide only year and quarter as input parameters. The following procedure should return the quarter beginning and end:

```
alter procedure spQuarter (
    @yearStr VARCHAR(7),
    @QuarterStr VARCHAR(20)
)
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @year INT = CAST(SUBSTRING(@yearStr, 1, 4) AS INT)

    DECLARE @QuarterId INT = (CASE
        WHEN @QuarterStr = 'jan-mar' THEN 4
        WHEN @QuarterStr = 'apr-jun' THEN 1
        WHEN @QuarterStr = 'jul-sep' THEN 2
        WHEN @QuarterStr = 'oct-dec' THEN 3
    END)

    DECLARE @startOfYStr VARCHAR(20) = CAST (@year AS VARCHAR) + '01' + '01'

    PRINT @yearStr
    PRINT @startOfYStr

    DECLARE @startDate DATE = CAST(@startOfYStr AS DATE)
    DECLARE @startOfQ DATE = DATEADD(quarter, @QuarterId, @startDate)
    DECLARE @endOfQ DATE = DATEADD(day, -1, DATEADD(quarter, @QuarterId + 1, @startDate))

    SELECT @startOfQ, @endOfQ
END
GO
```

**Tests:**

```
exec spQuarter '2014-15', 'jan-mar' --> 2015-01-01  2015-03-31
exec spQuarter '2014-15', 'apr-jun' --> 2014-04-01  2014-06-30
exec spQuarter '2014-15', 'oct-dec' --> 2014-10-01  2014-12-31
```

Some extra checking should be performed on input parameters, but it should be a good start for you need.

Comment: Did you know that `dateadd()` also works with quarters?

Comment: @shawnt00 - Not until now. Thanks for pointing out. I have already updated the code.

Comment: @Alexei thanks for your help but it will not work it shoud accept year as 2014-15

Comment: That 15 does not make any sense for me. If you receive the year in that particular form, you can define `@year as VARCHAR(7)` and fetch `@actualYear as CAST(SUBSTRING(@year, 4, 2) AS INT)`

Comment: @Alexei year will get start  from april 2014 to march 2015 so when i am passing 2014-15 jan-mar( 4 Quter) it shoud return first day of jan and last day of  march for year of 2015

Comment: @Alexei in my database i am saving year as 2014-15

Comment: Ok, so your fiscal year is not mapped on calendar year and you provide fiscal year as {yyyy}-{yy+1}. I have changed the procedure to work on that format, however, the most efficient storage is to store 2014 as int instead of 2014-15 as string (and still be able to do the math)

Answer (score 1):

You need to just pas year parameter like this '2014-2015' instead of 2014-15 and below sp will work

```
create proc spQuarter
(
@YEAR VARCHAR(10),
@Quarter VARCHAR(10),
)
AS
BEGIN

 DECLARE @QuarterId INT = (CASE
        WHEN @Quarter = 'jan-mar' THEN 1
        WHEN @Quarter = 'apr-jun' THEN 2
        WHEN @Quarter = 'jul-sep' THEN 3
        WHEN @Quarter = 'oct-dec' THEN 4
END)

DECLARE @PreYear VARCHAR(10) = (SELECT top 1 items from dbo.Split(@year,'-'))

DECLARE @NextYear VARCHAR(10)= (SELECT top 1 items from dbo.Split(@year,'-') 
                        where items not in(SELECT top 1 items from dbo.Split(@year,'-')))

DECLARE @SDate Datetime 

SET @SDate  = (Case @QuarterId When 1 then CONVERT(Datetime,'01-01-'+ @NextYear )
              when 2 then CONVERT(Datetime,'01-04-'+ @PreYear)
              when 3 then CONVERT(Datetime,'01-07-'+ @PreYear)
              when 4 then CONVERT(Datetime,'01-10-'+ @PreYear) end)

SELECT @SDate as StartDate ,DATEADD (dd, -1, DATEADD(qq, DATEDIFF(qq, 0, @SDate) +@QuarterId ,0)) as EndDate

END
```

Answer (score 0):

**Comments**

First some comments about your code:

There's no reason to use `select` inside these assignments. The second form is all you need and all the additional noise and nesting of parentheses is not helpful. There are cases where you really do need a subquery but simple expressions are not it.

```
-- bad
set @StartMonth = (select month('2014-'+substring(ltrim(rtrim(@Qmonth)),1,3)+'-01') as mnth1)
-- better
set @StartMonth = month('2014-' + substring(ltrim(rtrim(@Qmonth)), 1, 3) + '-01')
```

You started mixing in `select` syntax for reasons I'm not sure about. But notice that you can either say `select <result> = <expr>` or `select <expr> as <result>`. `as` is entirely optional but highly recommended.

```
-- error
select from_dt as (select DATEADD(month,@StartMonth-1,DATEADD(year,@ac_year-1900,0)))
-- ok
select DATEADD(month, @StartMonth-1, DATEADD(year, cast(@ac_year-1900 as int), 0)) as from_dt
```

There's another error in there where you tried to do subtraction with a string/character value. I think I got something closer to what you had in mind but I'm not promising that line of code would is quite right.

Next, your arguments were off in another snippet. I believe you wanted 3 characters at the 4th position in the second `set`. `Substring()`'s third argument needs to be number of characters length and not the ending position. So use `4, 3` rather than `5, 7`.

```
-- wrong part of the date
set @Endmonth =(select  month('2014-'+substring(ltrim(rtrim(@Qmonth)),5,7)+'-01') as month2)
-- correct part of the date
set @Endmonth = month('2014-' + substring(ltrim(rtrim(@Qmonth)), 4, 3) + '-01')
```

Those changes should get you back on the right track although you hadn't gotten to the point where you have to find the last day of the month for the end of the quarter. I'll go ahead and offer my own approach.

**Working Code**

```
declare @q int =
set @q = /* ignoring everything after the first three characters */
    case lower(substring(@QMonth, 1, 3))
        when 'jan' then 0  when 'apr' then 1  when 'jul' then 2  when 'oct' then 3
    end;

declare @y int;
set @y = cast(left(@ac_year, 4) as int); /* assuming this contains a value like '2014-15' */

set @StartMonth = dateadd(quarter, @q, dateadd(year, @y - 2000, '2000-01-01');
set @EndMonth   = dateadd(day, -1, dateadd(quarter, 1, @StartMonth));
```

You're going to need to look into output parameters to get the procedure to actually return the two date values. I'll let you handle that on your own.